# Accessing chrome.* APIs from local HTML

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. This is how my extension is structured:

I have a browser action defined such that clicking on it loads a local HTML file **default.html**. This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Example Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Does nothing.",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["extension.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

This is my **extension.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var newURL = chrome.extension.getURL('default.html');
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

This is my **default.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="donothing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <b>It works!</b>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to access chrome's currently open tabs in **donothing.js** and display some statistics in the default.html. I learn that I can not access chrome.* APIs within my **donothing.js**. If I have understood the docs correctly, I should declare and define a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) and pass messages as **donothing.js** --> **contentscript.js** --> **extension.js** and vice versa to achieve what I want to. Is there a simpler way to do this? Can someone explain the need for the content script here?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "access open tabs" ? What info do you need to get ? Also, I don't know where you learned that you cannot access chrome.* APIs within **donothing.js**, but it doesn't sound like a good source of knowledge :)

Comment: @warunsl your `default.html` is not a 'local' page but an extension page. The full chrome.* APIs for which you have requested the proper permissions will be available within donothing.js.